# Defining rule for firebase-database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm starting a new app using the firebase database and firebase auth. I'm not really familiar with setting up databases and its rules.

In short, the situation is as follows: The app/db has some users and components. A (auth)user can have access to multiple other users, and a user can contain multiple components. A user has access to components through users it has access to.

**Firebase situation**

I have a `user` table containing all users. These are Firebase.Auth users, and all id#s below are `auth.uid`s.

I have a `access` table, in which is defined what users have access to what other users. Normally, there is one 'hub' user, and several other users have access to this user.

```
users
    id1 {user info}
    id2 {user info}
    id3 {user info}
    id4 {user info}
    id5 {user info}
access
    id1
        id1 true
        id2 true
        id3 true
    id4
        id2 true
        id4 true
        id5 true
```

The above means that users `id1`, `id2` and `id3` have access to `id1`. Same for `id4`: `id2`, `id4` and `id5` have access to this user.

I also have a table of `groups` and `components`. A `component` is an element that I eventually want to read/write to. A `group` is simply a group of components grouped by a user (a hub, specifically, `id1` in the above example).

```
groups
    id1
        cm1 true
        cm2 true
    id4
        cm3 true
components
    cm1
        //contains some values to read/write
    cm2
        //contains some values to read/write
    cm3
        //contains some values to read/write
```

In the codesnippet above, there are two `groups`, `id1` and `id4`, corresponding to the users, which both have some components. The specifics of the components are in the `components` table.

**Question**

I want to make a firebase-rule that allows a `user` (i.e. the auth.uid) to read and write *inside* a `component` if and only if the following is true:

*The current `user` has access to a `user` (in the `access` table), which contains the `component` in its `group` table.*

How can I set this up with the database scheme above. Or should I change the DB scheme to achieve this in a good way?

**EDIT: I'm using firebase auth, which means that the Id of the current user is simply the auth.uid**

Comment: There is no way to go from a specific component to the users, since that would require a search across all groups. If you can map a component to a specific group it might be possible.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Adding a map from component to group would require me to duplicate some data. My gut feeling says this is bad practice, since all data manipulations on the connection between group and component should always be done twice. Or is it the way to go for this situation?

Comment: Data duplication is quite common in NoSQL databases. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)